# JMeter: Load test - how to separate the ramp up, actions and ramdown actions in a jmx script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, test-script

Currently, my scenario is set as below:
* Login
* Loop Controller - Business process such as create a quote or application
* Logout

But If I have to Make sure that Login and logout runs once per user and the Business process runs multiple iterations for a particular Period(Say 1 hour) , how do I handle this.?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is going for [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

[image]

For more complex conditions (including multiple clauses) you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/), the relevant condition for your setup would be the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(vars.getIteration() == 1,)}
```

[image]

In order to make some request(s) to run in loop for certain amount of time:

1. Put the request under [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and tick `Forever` box
2. Put the Loop Controller under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) and set "Runtime (seconds)" to `3600`

   [image]